# How do I display a Media entity reference field in a nested paragraph on a template?

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have been working on this for 2 days and I can't figure it out. I hope someone can help me.
I have a paragraph `(dinamic_columns_grid)` that has an entity reference field to another paragraph `(field_dinamic_column)` This nested paragraph has an entity reference field to a Media image field `(field_image)`. All the paragraphs have more fields but this is the one that is giving me problems.

I created a twig template for the first paragraph `(paragraph--dinamic-columns-grid.html.twig)` where I want to display the nested paragraph's fields individually. I know I could use `{{ content.field_dinamic_column }}` to display all of the results, and it does work, including the image field, but that's now what I want. All the fields in the code below are displaying correctly except the image field `(field_image)`. I have tried everything but I can't seem to make it work. Any help will be appreciate.

```
        {% for key, item in content.field_dinamic_column %}
            {{ item['#paragraph'].field_html_content.value|raw }} / text field.It works
            {{ item['#paragraph'].field_hide.value|raw }} / select field. It Works
            {{ item['#paragraph'].field_image }} / Media image field. It doesn't work 
         {% endfor %}
```

I like to be able to see the image or at the very least the url.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to append `.entity.field_image.entity.uri.value` to the media image field and use filerul(). See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251441/display-image-media-entities-view-from-node-to-twig-template

Comment: And never use ' |raw' . For a field containing HTML use ' processed_text' . See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231805/filter-raw-doesnt-show-entity-media-image

Comment: Thanks. node is not an available variable on the paragraph template. so `.entity.field_image.entity.uri.value` won't work. How would you implement it?

Comment: I didn't mention a node. Your question ends with a media image field which doesn't work for you and I suggested to append this code to the field. The link is only for further explanation what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts I finally figure it out, thanks to the comments above and a little investigation. I think my problem was that I assume that the machine name I need it to use for my nested image field was the one I give when I created the content type but that's not the case, I had to use the field of the media type in my case `field_media_image` instead of `field_image`.Below is the working code.

`{{ file_url( item['#paragraph'].field_image.entity.field_media_image.entity.uri.value ) }}`